# Advanced Javascript Obfuscation

Tags: javascript, browser, web, obfuscation, native-code

I've been training heavily in JS obfuscation, starting to know my way around all advanced concepts, but I recently found an obfuscated code, I believe it is some form of "Native Javascript Code", I just can't find ANY documentation on this type of obfuscation :

Here is a small extract :

```
'\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40'
```

It is called this way :

```
eval(eval('\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40'))
```

Since the code is the work of another and I encoutered it in a JS challenge I'm not posting the full code, so the example I gave won't work, but the full code does work.

So here is my question:
**What type of code is this? And where can I learn more about it?**

Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: Just paste that string in your browsers' console and be amazed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a string with the characters escaped. You can read it in the JavaScript console in any browser:

```
console.log('\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40')
```

will print:

```
"a=prompt('Entrez "
```

Comment: You don't need to pass it through a function at all. It's just character escape sequences.

Comment: You beat me to it! [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml) is a page explaining javascript escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks :) don't know how I didn't recognize that... Maybe because I hoped it would be something more advanced...

Comment: Yeah, I realized that you didn't need to call any function right after I posted it. D'oh!

Comment: Works in Safari and Firefox consoles too. :-)

Comment: Works in IE too. I should have said "any browser JavaScript console." :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's just escaped characters, one part outputting the string of a query and another actually running the returned string - try calling it in a console.

```
eval('\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\47\51')
```

Might help?

Comment: `escape` and `unescape` are for percent-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers is the ascii codes (http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) of characters (in Octal representation).
You can convert it to characters. This is used when somebody wants to make an `XSS attack`, or wants to hide the js code.

So the string what you written represents:

```
 a=prompt('Entrez
```

The js engines, browsers can translate the octal format to the 'real' string. With `eval` function it could run. (in case the 'translated' code has no syntax errors)